Controlling for variation in results of xGBoost cross validation
I am finding the nrounds that the cross validation for xgboost returns are highly variable. This of course translates to models with varying performance. This is especially a problem when I compare two different models as the comparison is dependent on what nrounds I set each model for based on separate cross validations. I have considered using the average or minimum from a set of cv runs, but even this does not seem to converge easily. Does anyone have any other suggestions to remove the variability? Below is an example of the code I am running and some output:
n_runs <- 10
best_iterations <- numeric(n_runs)
for (i in 1:n_runs) {
    set.seed(i) # For reproducibility
    cv <- xgb.cv(data = dtrain, nrounds = 1000, nthread = 14, nfold = 4,  early_stopping_rounds=20, metrics = "rmse",
                 max_depth = 3, eta = .1, objective = "reg:tweedie", weight=df$EHY) #
    best_iterations[i] <- cv$best_iteration
}
# Print the best iterations for each run
print(best_iterations)
mean(best_iterations)
min(best_iterations)

print(best_iterations)
 [1] 214 221 207 241 197 229 210 245 223 159
> mean(best_iterations)
[1] 214.6
> min(best_iterations)
[1] 159


Using a seed value should make how samples are split into folds consistent, but you're using a different seed in every pass through the loop. Even if folds were identical, xgboost is still stochastic when it comes to feature selection. Repeated cross validation is a common approach when fitting models, and you'd actually hurt your fitting process by making identical folds each time.

@Seth This is good advice. Right now I have settled on repeated cv but I have trouble comparing two models. For example, when I add variables to the model I can get what looks like a worse performing model (gini). But it doesnt make sense for a model with more information to perform worse. I think this is mostly due to the noise inherent in xgboost and the cv.
